# Quickblox iOS notification when a new dialog is added

Tags: ios, notifications, chat, quickblox

Is there a iOS notification that we get in ServiceManager (QMServicesManager), chatService to notify the app that a new Dialog is added for the user. Basically a brand new chat request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use QuickBlox's System notifications to send the message to the recipient after creating a dialog

```
let message: QBChatMessage = QBChatMessage()
    let params = NSMutableDictionary()
    params["event_type"] = "NewDialogCreated"
    params["dialogId"] = <dialogId or the information you need to pass>
    message.customParameters = params
    message.recipientID = UInt(recipientId)!

    QBChat.instance.sendSystemMessage(message) { (Error) in

    }
```

and recipient could receive this message in QBChatdelegate

```
#pragma mark QBChatDelegate

func chatDidReceiveSystemMessage(message: QBChatMessage!) {

}
```